# Transforming panal data

Tags: r, time, reshape, series

I am working with a dataset of countries, with different values for different points in time. There is one observation each month, so I have used the as.date fucntion such that dates are 01-07-2018, 01-08-2018 etc. 
For each country and each date exist a corresponding value. 
I want to transform this into an dataframe, where all the countries values are aggregated at a date. 
I have tried the reshape function such that

```
reshape(Origin_wide, idvar = "Origin", timevar = "V5", direction = "wide")
```

V5 being the date variable and Origin being the country. 
This is as far as I can tell dropping the as.date set, such that the dates and the corresponding values is no longer treated as such. 
Can it be done in a more smooth way ? The time series aspect of the data series disseapears ones the reshape function is lost, such that i cannot difference the time series or plot it by date etc. 
Furthermore the dates are getting a "value" prefix, which is the same problem as far as I can tell.

Here is the data structure as it is:

```
|       V5            |        Origin    |  Value   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|
|      01-09-2017     |        USA       |     45   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|
|      01-10-2017     |        USA       |     47   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|
|      01-11-2017     |        USA       |     49   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|
|      01-09-2017     |        Canada    |     7    |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|
|      01-10-2017     |        Canada    |     13   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|
|      01-11-2017     |        Canada    |     17   |
|---------------------|------------------|----------|
```

And here is how I would like it to look:

```
    |       V5            |        Canada    |  USA     |
    |---------------------|------------------|----------|
    |      01-09-2017     |        7         |     45   |
    |---------------------|------------------|----------|
    |      01-10-2017     |        13        |     47   |
    |---------------------|------------------|----------|
    |      01-11-2017     |        17        |     49   |
    |---------------------|------------------|----------|
```

Hope this makes sense. 
To reproduce a random  small version of the data :

```
    set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(Value = sample(1:10), Origin = sample(c("Mexico", "USA","Canada"), 10, replace = TRUE))
dates <- sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2018/05/01'), by="month"), 10, replace = TRUE)
Data <- cbind(dates,Data)
```

[A look on the data as produced by the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qwue.png)
[image]

As it is clear here, the values are not defined for all the dates. When this is the case, the value for that date is = 0. So in my first try with reshape it produces NA's for all the dates where there where no observations, which was perfect, because i was able to just put in 0's.

Comment: Could you maybe provide a minimal reproducible example, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including your data and your expected outcome.

Comment: Yes of course. It is here now !

Comment: I appreciate you adding some data, but you are much more likely to get help here if your data is reproducible. The comment above included a link that explains how to do that - please read it. Here is specific r [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of particularity regarding this question. 
I have added som code that should recreate a version of the data I am working with. Please let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Recreate your data

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(
  V5 = rep(c("01-09-2017", "01-10-2017", "01-11-2017"), 2),
  Origin = rep(c("USA", "Canada"), each = 3),
  Value = c(45, 47, 49, 7, 13, 17)
)
```

### Code

```
tbl %>%
  spread(Origin, Value)
```

### Result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  V5         Canada   USA
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 01-09-2017      7    45
2 01-10-2017     13    47
3 01-11-2017     17    49
```

I am not sure it is a good idea to replace the `NA` by `0` because those truly are missing values, not values of `0`. But if you really want to do this, then you can do:

```
result <- tbl %>%
  spread(Origin, Value)

result[is.na(result)] <- 0
```

Note: your toy example is random and does not represent the pattern of your actual data. Running the code on it outputs a pretty ugly wide format. When you create a toy example, try to make sure that it reflects the characteristics of your real data.

Comment: Thanks ! This seems to be exactly what I need. 
I get the dates as column, is there anyway to get them as rownames, but still keep the formatting, such that I am able to perform operation based on the date values? 

Such that I can take diff() and ge the first difference. If I try this now, i get the error_: Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: If you want to transform your `V5` variable as rownames, you can use `tibble::column_to_rownames()` (Note that you didn't ask anything about that in your question though, so I won't edit my answer or it would not answer your question anymore).

Comment: I did miss your last question about `NA` though, so I will edit my answer for this. (And if my comment above is not clear enough and if you edit your question, I will add the `column_to_rownames()` in my answer as well).

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have tried to figure out was wrong with my example. Could you elaborate on your note regarding this?

Comment: Are you referring to your toy example? If so, you can see that your real sample data has a pattern (`USA` and `Canada` have the same number of observations at the same dates. This leads to a wide format with no `NA`). In contrast, your toy example is created with random sampling without any repetition pattern. So that gives a wide format with lots of `NA` everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, my first example was not representative of my data. My toy example was. I am new to stackoverflow - I will be more precise the next time. Thank you for taking your time to help me, and point out the wrongs !

Comment: No worries! I am glad I could help